# Is the use of class based components still recommended as the standard industrial practice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Although the code I wrote works in the browser, it tells me that the use of constructor is deprecated and useless in the following code

```
`class ArrList extends React.Component{ 
    constructor(props){
      super(props)
   }
   render(){
    const {array} = this.props;
    const arrList = array.map((arr) => <List key={arr} li={arr} />)
    return arrList;
    }
}`

enter code here
```

also, **super** was cross in the code but it works. So is it advisable to continue to use class-based or stay with functional based

Comment: I do recommend using class base components when you want to manage state and/or need to manage life cycle hooks. Although you can import useState and useEffect etc... In class based components state is merged with previous state and also the use of life cycle hooks is more (at least in my opinion) convenient.

Comment: In some cases, you are pretty much forced to use class components, such as when implementing [Error Boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html), but generally, function components are the future.

Comment: Once you feel the teste of the react hooks, you will never go back to class components.

Answer (score 2):

It must be telling you that `constructor` is not really required in your example code. You are doing nothing inside `constructor`.

So, in your code, you can remove:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
}
```

`Constructors` are mostly used to *initialize* state and *bind* event handler methods with `this` i.e. instance. Example:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    foo: '',
    bar: ''

  }
  this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}
```

> If you don’t initialize state and you don’t bind methods, you don’t need to implement a constructor for your React component.

> The constructor for a React component is called before it is mounted. When implementing the constructor for a React.Component subclass, you should call super(props) before any other statement. Otherwise, this.props will be undefined in the constructor, which can lead to bugs.

Read more: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

---

#### Class vs Function:

**There is no clear answer for this**. You should use whatever you like or maybe both. But you may notice that the codebase become shorter when using functions. Class might be confusing, but functions are simple. But again, this **depends** on the programmer.

Note that [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html) (custom or built-in) cannot be used in class components. So, if you want to use hooks, use function components.

Read more: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html

Comment: Thanks it really helps

Answer (score 1):

You don't need constructor and super anymore if you use Babel. However, I'd recommend using hooks and functional components instead of classes, it will make your react codebase shorter and more readable.